# Return each column from google sheet json data into array of arrays

Tags: jquery, ajax

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1VC633BXpMElJjRWvIRuZIP7UrEhuw6BdscnrV2heox0/1/public/full?alt=json',
    success: function(data) {
      var entry = data.feed.entry;
      var getTitle = Object.keys(entry[0]).slice(6);
      console.log(getTitle);
      
      var arr = [...entry].map((el)=>{
        return el.gsx$fruits.$t;
      }).filter((el) => {
        return el.trim();
      });
      console.log(arr);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code above will return the keys of each column:`["gsx$fruits", "gsx$animals"]`

and all strings from fruits column: `["apple", "banana"]`

After long hours of trial and errors I still cant achieve my desired output:

```
[["apple", "banana"],["monkey", "dog", "cat", "bear"]]
```

Your help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're only mapping using the `gsx$fruits` that's why you only get those, if you map both, using `getTitle` you'll get the desired results

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1VC633BXpMElJjRWvIRuZIP7UrEhuw6BdscnrV2heox0/1/public/full?alt=json',
    success: function(data) {
      var entry = data.feed.entry;
      var getTitle = Object.keys(entry[0]).slice(6);
      console.log(getTitle);
      var arr = getTitle.map(title=>{
        return entry.map((el)=>{
          return el[title].$t;
        }).filter((el) => {
          return el.trim();
        });
      });
      console.log(arr);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```